# Kentor.AuthServices is appending SAMLRequest directly to sign-in URL which causes 403 Forbidden

Tags: saml-2.0, federation, kentor-authservices

I'm using AuthServices to implement single sign in.  Everything works OK if I go directly to the IDP's sign in page:

`https://fedserver/saml2sso?SPID=https://myapp.com`

However if I click a link in my app which requires a login, it redirects to /AuthServices/SignIn, which in turn, redirects to the sign in URL but with "&SAMLRequest=" appended to the URL. This causes a 403 Request Forbidden response from the remote server.

`https://fedserver/saml2sso?SPID=https://myapp.com&SAMLRequest=.....`

If I delete this extra parameter and submit, I then get signed in OK and sent back to my app.

What I can't work out is, which end is misbehaving? Should the remote server allow the (seemingly redundant SAMLRequest parameter, or should AuthServices not be appending it in the first place?

**EDIT:**
I've tried to use an alternative commercial component (ComponentSpace SAML2)  and it works OK with the same IdP server out of the box, so it looks like this might be a bug or configuration problem with Kentor.  I'd still like to know if this is solvable with Kentor.

Comment: What is the other component doing? POSTing to that Url, or simply not appending the parameter? Do you have any more information from the Idp side about details behind that 403 error?

Comment: Also, is that base url (with the SPID) coming from Idp metadata or have you specifically configured it? I would assume the `SAMLRequest` has all the information needed by Idp and there is no need for SPID in that case.

Comment: I think the IdP is incorrectly parsing the the SPID from the URL - it's just taking everyting to the right of the equals, as it doesn't even like a trailing slash or space, so I'm thinking the error might be on the IdP side. Then again, I'm not sure why Kentor is appending data to the sign-in URL - it shouldn't be touching it and that doesn't seem to be normal behaviour.

Comment: The SPID is part of the configuration I was asked to use, the problem remains if I remove it (in fact visiting the URL without the SPID also results in an immediate 400 error)

Comment: I think the SPID is the non-standard part. SamlRequest is what's in the standard. You might also try changing to POST binding instead of redirect.

Comment: POST seems to cause the same problem.  :(